# For loop to execute jquery function not executed

Tags: jquery, for-loop, datepicker

I am new to jquery. I want to implement the jquery `datepicker` for a loop . So i wrote the following :

```
for( var m = 1; m < 6 ; m++ )
{
    $(function() {
    $("#dt_id"+m).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: '1/1/1970',
    yearRange: '1910:2010'
    });
});

}
```

But it is not showing the calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$(function() { ... })` block is either in the wrong place, or unnecessary.  It's equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` but because you're trying to use `m` inside a callback it will always have the value 6 by the time the callback is invoked.

If you don't have a similar block elsewhere, wrap the *entire* loop with `$(function())` call.

```
$(function() {

    for (var m = 1; m < 6 ; m++) {
        $("#dt_id"+m).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: '1/1/1970',
            yearRange: '1910:2010'
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thnaks. But its coming for the first element ie for m=1 only !

Comment: what sort of element is `#dt_idX` ?